# How to associate class property with instance property

Tags: c#, optimization

I have some models for Person, TaskListitem and Task as shown below.
I am currently using BindingList to bind to datagrid to show task in datagrid. I am using it because I have to show DeveloperName and ReviewerName in the grid.

**Background:** this is a code from Task Tracking Program (learning project). Client is written in C#.
Server is written in Ruby. Server stores data in activerecord tables for People, Tasks.
Client also locally caches the same in sqlite DB.

Currently Globals.People is defined as

```
public static class Globals
{
    ...
    public static List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
    ...
}
```

and the classes Person, TaskListitem and Task as shown below:

```
public class Person : TimeStamp, IEquatable<Person>
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string trigram { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public eLevel level { get; set; }
    public string internal_object_id { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public int unread_objects_count { get; set; }
    public int documents_count { get; set; }
    public int work_tasks_count { get; set; }
    public int review_tasks_count { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Person obj)
    {
        ...
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        ...
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class TaskListItem : Task
{
    public string taskName
    {
        get { return this.name + " - " + this.title; }
    }
    public string DeveloperName
    {
        get { return Globals.People.Find(x => x.id == this.developer_id).name; }
    }
    public string ReviewerName
    {
        get { return Globals.People.Find(x => x.id == this.reviewer_id).name; }
    }
}


public class Task : TimeStamp
{
    public Task()
    {
        ...
        if (Globals.People.Count == 0) Globals.People.Add(new Person { id = 0, name = "DummyUser", level = eLevel.Master });
        developer_id = Globals.People.First().id;
        reviewer_id = Globals.People.First().id;
        ...
    }

    public TaskListItem AsTaskListItem()
    {
    ...
    }

    public int developer_id { get; set; }
    public int reviewer_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

But then as I was learning I found that Static object must not be used to preserve state. So I started searching for an alternative to my implementation. I was able to solve it partially by returning DeveloperName and ReviewerName along with task. So I don't have to use to Static List.
But now I am facing a problem that when I retrieve Tasks from Cache. I am unable to merge it with retrieved data of People. 
How Do I Merge it. My above partial solution requires me to retrieve redundant data along with each Task (i.e. Person names with each Task as client has already retrieved all people data).

[Complete Code](https://bitbucket.org/AEonAX/grind/src/adc84743ac5fa01d63615244708f634c3bb1c0a5/GrindClient/Grind.Common/Models.cs?at=master)

Please comment for suggestions and improvements.

Comment: Can you explain (or show) what DOESN'T work?

Comment: I basically to want create TaskListItem from Task with DeveloperName and ReceiverName filled from another non static Person List. Or what I am thinking is wrong?

Comment: If possible what changes should I make to TaskListItem  So as to get Developername and ReviewerName from non Static Person List.

Comment: Or something Like I have List<Task> and ObservableCollection<Person> How do I merge them into BindingList<TaskListItem> So TaskListItem has DeveloperName taken from ObservableCollection<Person>  corresponding to developer_id of Task.

Comment: If by static list you're referring to the list of ALL `Person` objects, there's nothing fundamentaly wrong about that

Comment: Yes I had a static List<Person> People holding all people. But I learned that will be not thread safe. That is If later I started using backgroundworker I might race conditions and all other trouble.